# why can't I get this code to run I keep getting type error: 'Method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, debugging

I keep getting error codes on this code and I do not know why.... it keeps telling me method object is not subscriptable no matter what I do..  Any help is appreciated.  I also know my code might not be pretty. I'm still just learning Python. Literally almost anything I do I'm getting an error code and I don't know how to fix it. Ive tried almost everything I can think of.

```
import string


def load_words(file_name):
    '''
    file_name (string): the name of the file containing 
    the list of words to load    
    
    Returns: a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.
    
    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    '''
    print('Loading word list from file...')
    
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    line = file.readline()
    word_list = line.split()
    
    print('  ', len(word_list), 'words loaded.') #word_list is the list of valid words 
    file.close()
    return word_list

def is_word(word_list, word):
    '''
    Determines if word is a valid word, ignoring
    capitalization and punctuation (" !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")

    word_list (list): list of words in the dictionary.
    word (string): a possible word.
    
    Returns: True if word is in word_list, False otherwise

    Example:
    >>> is_word(word_list, 'bat') returns
    True
    >>> is_word(word_list, 'asdf') returns
    False
    '''
    
    word = word.lower
    word = word.strip("!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")
    return word in word_list


def get_story_string():
    """
    Returns: a joke in encrypted text.
    """
    f = open("story.txt", "r")
    story = str(f.read())
    f.close()
    return story

WORDLIST_FILENAME = 'words.txt'

class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        '''
        Initializes a Message object
                
        text (string): the message's text

        a Message object has two attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words
        '''
        self.message_text = text
        self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)

    def get_message_text(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.message_text outside of the class
        
        Returns: self.message_text
        '''
        return self.message_text


    def get_valid_words(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access a copy of self.valid_words outside of the class
        
        Returns: a COPY of self.valid_words
        '''
        return self.get_valid_words[:]
    

    def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
        '''
        Creates a dictionary that can be used to apply a cipher to a letter.
        The dictionary maps every uppercase and lowercase letter to a
        character shifted down the alphabet by the input shift. The dictionary
        should have 52 keys of all the uppercase letters and all the lowercase
        letters only.        
        
        shift (integer): the amount by which to shift every letter of the 
        alphabet. 0 <= shift < 26

        Returns: a dictionary mapping a letter (string) to 
                 another letter (string). 
        '''
        lower = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        lower_values = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        shift_lower_values = lower_values[shift:] + lower_values[:shift]
        
        upper = list(string.ascii_uppercase)                 
        upper_values = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
        upper_shift_values = upper_values[shift:] + upper_values[:shift]

        full_keys = lower + upper
        full_values = shift_lower_values + upper_shift_values

        self.shift_dict = dict(zip(full_keys, full_values))
        return self.shift_dict        



    def apply_shift(self, shift):
        '''
        Applies the Caesar Cipher to self.message_text with the input shift.
        Creates a new string that is self.message_text shifted down the
        alphabet by some number of characters determined by the input shift        
        
        shift (integer): the shift with which to encrypt the message.
        0 <= shift < 26

        Returns: the message text (string) in which every character is shifted
             down the alphabet by the input shift
        '''
        message = self.get_message_text()       
        new_string = ""                         
        shiftDictonary = self.build_shift_dict(shift)       
        for letter in message:                  
            if letter in shiftDictonary:
                new_string += shiftDictonary[letter]
            else:
                new_string += letter
        return new_string

class PlaintextMessage(Message):
 
    def __init__(self, text, shift):
        '''
        Initializes a PlaintextMessage object        
        
        text (string): the message's text
        shift (integer): the shift associated with this message

        A PlaintextMessage object inherits from Message and has five attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
            self.shift (integer, determined by input shift)
            self.encrypting_dict (dictionary, built using shift)
            self.message_text_encrypted (string, created using shift)

        Hint: consider using the parent class constructor so less 
        code is repeated
        '''
        Message.__init__(self, text)
        self.shift = shift
        self.encrypting_dict = self.build_shift_dict(shift)
        self.message_text_encrypted = self.apply_shift(shift)

    def get_shift(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.shift outside of the class
        
        Returns: self.shift
        '''
        return self.shift

    def get_encrypting_dict(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access a copy self.encrypting_dict outside of the class
        
        Returns: a COPY of self.encrypting_dict
        '''
        return self.encrypting_dict.copy()


    def get_message_text_encrypted(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.message_text_encrypted outside of the class
        
        Returns: self.message_text_encrypted
        '''
        return self.message_text_encrypted
    
    
    def change_shift(self, shift):
        '''
        Changes self.shift of the PlaintextMessage and updates other 
        attributes determined by shift (ie. self.encrypting_dict and 
        message_text_encrypted).
        
        shift (integer): the new shift that should be associated with this message.
        0 <= shift < 26

        Returns: nothing
        '''
        self.__init__(self.message_text, shift)

class CiphertextMessage(Message):
  def __init__(self, text):
       
       Message.__init__(self, text)
     
  def decrypt_message(self):
   best_shift = None
   best_real_words = 0
   best_msg = ""

   for s in range(26):
       decrypted_text = self.apply_shift(s)
       words = decrypted_text.split()
       real_words = sum([is_word(self.get_valid_words(), w) for w in words])
       if real_words > best_real_words:
          best_shift = s
          best_real_words = real_words
          best_msg = decrypted_text

   return (best_shift, best_msg)
   

#Example test case (PlaintextMessage)
plaintext = PlaintextMessage('hello', 2)
print('Expected Output: jgnnq')
print('Actual Output:', plaintext.get_message_text_encrypted())
    
#Example test case (CiphertextMessage) 
#Uncomment the following lines when you have completed your CiphertextMessage class
ciphertext = CiphertextMessage('jgnnq')
print('Expected Output:', (24, 'hello'))
print('Actual Output:', ciphertext.decrypt_message())
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
word = word.lower
```

You are giving `word` a reference to a method which propagates to everything you use `word` for afterwards. You probably wanted to write this:

```
word = word.lower()
```

Consider [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=type%20hinting) as it will allow your IDE to catch this kind of mistake easily.